# Make SQL column to be a XML node of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xslt

I want to transfer the first XML file into the format of the second one, essentially the main difference is that I don't want the repeating values of the masterBatchNo. Instead, I only want one unique value of the masterBatchNo and make the other attributes child nodes. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: It is hard to figure out what tables your columns come from when you don't use aliases. It would help if you could post the table structures.

Comment: they are essentially coming from one table, the INNER JOIN joins the two tables when the masterBatchNo match each other

Comment: What table has `masterBatchNo` as primary key? What table does `stage` come from?

Comment: stage comes from PV_MasterBatch table and both tables have masterBatchNo, the PV_Batch table has the primary key, but I don't think it matters since both tables contain the same masterBatchNo columns.

Comment: Is `masterBatchNo` the primary key in `PV_MasterBatch`?

Comment: it is the primary key in PV_MasterBatch, but masterBatchNo repeats in the PV_Batch table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for xml path` instead to get more control over how the XML is constructed. Use `PV_Batch` in a derived table to create the nested XML and `@` to create attributes.

The `exists` clause is there to exclude rows from `PV_MasterBatch` that will not have any child nodes generated from `PV_Batch`.

```
select MB.masterBatchNo as [@masterBatchNo],
       (
       select B.processStage as [@processStage],
              B.processBatchNo as [@processBatchNo]
       from PV_Batch as B
       where B.masterBatchNo = MB.masterBatchNo and
             B.projectid = @varProjectID
       for xml path('tempTable'), type
       )
from PV_MasterBatch as MB
where MB.stage = @varStage and
      exists (
             select *
             from PV_Batch as B
             where B.masterBatchNo = MB.masterBatchNo and
                   B.projectid = @varProjectID
             )
for xml path('PV_Batch'), root('Root')
```